# Cleanest way to implement a conditional with helper/template in Meteor 0.8.0 (Blaze)

Tags: javascript, meteor

In Meteor 0.7 and earlier I had a generalized conditional `#withif` block helper that combines the `#if` and `#with` block helpers: It renders some contents with the data context set to the object in question when it existed, and something else with the default data context if it didn't exist:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper "withif", (obj, options) ->
  if obj then options.fn(obj) else options.inverse(this)
```

The usage in a template would be something like the following, where `doc` has a field `foo`:

```
{{#withif doc}}
    {{> doSomethingWith foo}}
{{else}}
    Document doesn't exist!
{{/withif}}
```

In Meteor 0.8, this seems to be [much more convoluted to do](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#new-pattern-for-defining-custom-block-helpers). Basically, I'd like this block helper to choose between `UI.contentblock` and `UI.elseblock` and set the data context appropriately based on whether the referenced object exists in the context or not. What's the cleanest way to do this?

I'm aware that I could just deconstruct this as

```
{{#if this}}
    {{> UI.contentBlock this}}
{{else}}
    {{> UI.elseBlock}}
{{/if}}
```

However, I avoided this in Meteor 0.7 and earlier due to the unnecessary performance penalty versus the helper above. If it's possible to show that this doesn't get any slower in Blaze, I'd be happy to stick with it (I know Blaze generates code for rendering).

Comment: Isn't your `#withif` working exactly like `#with`?

Comment: @PeppeL-G `#with` doesn't support an `else` block, does it?

Comment: Yes it does. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/spacebars#with It was supported before spacebars was used too.

Comment: @PeppeL-G What is the difference between that and https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ui/builtins.js#L49, which says *Unlike Spacebars.With, there's no else case and no conditional logic.* ?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with their code, but what you're linking to is not the `{{#with}}`-helper, but just a function that changes what to render (the context) (kind of). The `{{#with}}`-helper is implemented here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/spacebars-runtime.js#L216 As you see, it makes use of `UI.With`, as you linked to.